# Where are the rest of my API results?

Tags: bug, api

On the API's [complex queries](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max) documentation page, there is a link to [Comments with at least a score of 10 on Ask Ubuntu](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&filter=default&site=askubuntu&run=true).

I have made two changes, neither of which should mess with the logic.

- Increased page size to 100
- Adjust the filter to include the `total` element in the wrapper

This can be found via this link: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#pagesize=100&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&filter=!9YdnSPuG8&site=askubuntu&run=true

In this result, it shows that there are a total of 804 comments that have a score of at least 10 on Ask Ubuntu. [SEDE agrees](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/448038)

**However**, that means [page 9](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#page=9&pagesize=100&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&filter=!9YdnSPuG8&site=askubuntu&run=true) should have 4 comments on it. Instead it returns:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9894,
  "total": 804
}
```

[Page 8](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#page=8&pagesize=100&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&filter=!9YdnSPuG8&site=askubuntu&run=true) only has 69 results.

Pages 7 and below all return 100 results each.

```
Page 1 - 100
     2   100
     3   100
     4   100
     5   100
     6   100
     7   100
     8    69
     9     0
         ---
         769
```

Where are the other 35 comments that the `total` element says should be there?