# API doesn't return "answer.tags" field if I also asked for "answer.share_link"

Tags: bug, api

When I load an answer via the Stack Exchange API, the `answer.tags` field disappears if the filter also includes the `answer.share_link` field.

Normal query, filter `!9YdnSLHTQ`: ([run it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=356178&filter=!9YdnSLHTQ&site=softwareengineering&run=true))

```
/2.2/answers/356178?order=desc&sort=activity&site=softwareengineering&filter=!9YdnSLHTQ
```

With a filter including "share_link" `!9YdnSLHPy`: ([run it](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=356178&filter=!9YdnSLHPy&site=softwareengineering&run=true))

```
/2.2/answers/356178?order=desc&sort=activity&site=softwareengineering&filter=!9YdnSLHPy
```

(The answer in this example is chosen totally at random and has no special significance.)

The filters can be plugged into the [filter debugger](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter) to verify that both include the `answer.tags` field. I have verified that there is no difference between the filters except that the second filter also requests a `share_link`.

This is not specific to the `/answers` endpoint. Other API endpoints that return answer objects seem to have the same problem.

When I run the second query, the first time it will contain an empty array for the `tags`. For subsequent requests (using either query), no `tags` field is present. When I run the first query again, the `tags` field will still be missing for a while, but re-appear at some point (on the order of minutes).

So I think we can blame caching?

Importantly, **this makes API requests stateful** – previous requests affect the results of subsequent requests for a short while.

This caching could make the above behaviour difficult to reproduce. But since I could reproduce it multiple times consistently, I'm confident the problem is real.

Possibly related:

- [Filter doesn't consistently return comment bodies](https://stackapps.com/q/4975/) (2014, no answer)
  [reposted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301090) (2017, no answer)
- [Creating an API filter with comment.body_markdown but without comment.body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247899/) (2015, no answer)
- [API doesn't return 'body_markdown' on comment endpoint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269164/) (2015, no answer)
- [Where are the rest of my API results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276712/) (2016, no answer)
- [API cache behavior can be exploited to hide posts from API clients](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305590) (2018, fixed) – another case of wonky caching. Was fixed by not caching empty responses. My case might still be due to the same problem if `answer` or `answer.tags` is cached independently, as the absence of `answer.tags` erases this field from subsequent responses.